# How to store heightmap efficiently?

Tags: python, sqlite, storage, heightmap

I store a game world (2D array of 5,000 x 5,000 int between -100 and 900) in an SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE map (x SMALLINT, y SMALLINT, h SMALLINT);
```

With `VACCUM` after `INSERT` it takes 500MB. I can compress (lzma) the file to 35-40MB but to use it I need to unzip. How do I store that so it could still run on a Raspberry Pi? A 2D array of int, or a list of 3-int tuples? Speed is not important but RAM and file size are.

Comment: What is the range of values for each height?  What regularities can you exploit?

Comment: Height range : -100, 900. 
It's pseudo-random. I use a custom adaptation of the [smooth noise algo](https://lodev.org/cgtutor/randomnoise.html) to generate it.

Comment: "*Speed is not important but RAM and file size are.*" Then don't store, just generate every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the HDF5 file format, with pyTables.
The outcome is a ~20MB file for the exact same data, directly usable by the application.
Here is how I create it:

```
import tables

db_struct = {
    'x': tables.Int16Col(),
    'y': tables.Int16Col(),
    'h': tables.Int16Col()
}
h5file = tables.open_file("my_file.h5", mode="w", title='Map')
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=9, complib='lzo')
group = h5file.create_group('/', 'group', 'Group')
table = h5file.create_table(group, 'map', db_struct, filters=filters)
heights = table.row

for y in range(0, int(MAP_HEIGHT)):
    for x in range(0, int(MAP_WIDTH)):
        heights['x'] = x
        heights['y'] = y
        heights['h'] = h
        heights.append()
    table.flush()

table.flush()
h5file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 10 bits to store each height, so 10 bytes can store 8 heights, and thus 31.25Mo can store all 25,000,000 of them.  You can figure out which block of 10 bytes stores a desired height (how depends on how you arrange them), and a little bit shifting can isolate the specific height you want (since every height will be split between 2 adjacent bytes).

Comment: Why not, but could you point to a documentation on how to do that in python ? I remember doing that kind of thing when I coded in C more than 10 years ago, but doing so in python is a mystery for me